# NATS discards the queue data

Tags: redis, nats.io

I am exploring the [NATS](https://nats.io/) for queuing and currently i am using redis `lists`. I stuck in below scenario, which easily manageable in redis:

1) There is one daemon which pushing the value in queue and one daemon which continuously reading from queue. If my reading daemon get stopped, redis starts storing data in queue . Once i start read daemon it pops from that last value where it got stopped like FIFO. In this there is no chance to loss my data. Is there any same provision providing by NATS?

2) If my redis server goes down, i can retrieve data ( leaving few) which already available in queue. If NATS server goes down can i retrieve my data?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the features of the core NATS platform, [NATS Streaming](https://nats.io/documentation/streaming/nats-streaming-intro/) provides the following:

1. **At-least-once-delivery** - NATS Streaming offers message acknowledgements between publisher and server (for publish operations) and between subscriber and server (to confirm message delivery). Messages are persisted by the server in memory or secondary storage (or other external storage) and will be redelivered to eligible subscribing clients as needed.
2. **Message/event persistence** - NATS Streaming offers configurable message persistence either in-memory or via flat files. The storage subsystem uses a public interface that allows contributors to develop their own custom implementations.